# Wordpress - Polylang - Missing home page

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I'm using Polylang to make my blog available in 6 languages. Globally it's working very well but I have one issue that I have not managed to solve. I posted it in the Wordpress area but got no response.

Default language is FR which means that the default homepage is the following:
https://www.laurentwillen.be

each other version of the home page is using the following structure:
https://www.laurentwillen.be/[language]

It works for all languages except for English while there is no difference in the configuration of that language.

Example:
https://www.laurentwillen.be/nl/ works

https://www.laurentwillen.be/es/ works

https://www.laurentwillen.be/en/ doesn't work and returns a 404 which is then redirected to the default home in French.

Do you have any idea of what goes wrong ?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: What is your default language in WordPress options? Maybe default is english and your website address without language suffix is treated as english thats why you get 404 response. What is happening when you add french suffix to your address?

Comment: French is the default language, all the other ones have been added afterwards but only EN was not working but now i have discovered the issue, it was coming from a conflicting category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have not created the English version of your homepage. Plugin can't find the EN version of the page. IF the page already exist try to delete it and re-create it using polylang "+" option.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I don't have a home page as such, the home page only retrieves all the articles from all the categories but there is no "physical" page behind. I haven't created any page for NL, DE, ES, IT and it works. Only EN doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: for Polylang plugin to work correctly you need to create the homepage for each language. Then you can assign your default homepage in settings/reading to homepage you created.

Comment: Thanks, my theme works without a home and I can't create one but you made me think and I ended up finding a solution. The issue was coming from a category bearing the same name as the language (en) and conflicting with a dynamic home. I removed it and now it works.